# Create linked service with key Vault using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

Here is my problem, I am trying to create linked service using python sdk and I was successful if I provide the storage account name and key. But I would like to create Linked service with key vaults reference, the below runs fine and creates the linked service. However when I go to datafactory and test connection.. it fails.. Please help!

```
store = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name ='LS_keyVault_Dev')
storage_string = AzureKeyVaultSecretReference( store=store, secret_name = 'access_key')

ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
```

**Error Message**

```
Invalid storage connection string provided to 'AzureTableConnection'. Check the storage connection string in configuration. No valid combination of account information found.
```

Comment: You should probably give [Key Vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) a try.

Comment: thanks for your response @rickvdbosch - I think LinkedServiceReference and AzureKeyVaultSecretReference Classes is for Key Vaults. Do you have any samples with similar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, it created the linked service successfully, and I navigate to the portal to `Test connection`, it also works, you could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the azure keyvault in the portal -> `Secrets` -> `Create a secret`, I'm not sure why you can use `access_key` as the name of the secret, pey my test, it is invalid. So in my sample, I use `accesskey` as the name of the secret, then store the `Connection string` of the storage account.

[image]

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Access policies` of the keyvault, add the MSI of your data factory with correct secret permission. If you did not enable the MSI of the data factory, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) to generate it, this is used to for the `Azure Key Vault` linked service to access your keyvault secret.

[image]

3.Navigate to the `Azure Key Vault` linked service of your data factory, make sure the connection is successful.

[image]

4.Use the code below to create the storage linked service.

Version of the libraries:

```
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-mgmt-datafactory==0.9.0
```

---

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

subscription_id = '<subscription-id>'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='<client-id>', secret='<client-secret>', tenant='<tenant-id>')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

rg_name = '<resource-group-name>'
df_name = 'joyfactory'
ls_name = 'storageLinkedService'

store = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name ='AzureKeyVault1') # AzureKeyVault1 is the name of the Azure Key Vault linked service
storage_string = AzureKeyVaultSecretReference( store=store, secret_name = 'accesskey')

ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
print(ls)
```

[image]

5.Go back to the linked service page, refresh and test the connection, it works fine.

[image]